# Need excel VBA code to run in infinite loop that increment the seconds even though we close the RDC connection in which the excel is running

Tags: excel, vba, infinite-loop

I am new to VBA. I have a requirement to write a program that should run in the infinite loop even though we close the RDC connection on which my code is running.

Steps to repro:
Open a RDC connection to a system in which your code is there.
 Run the Code. 
 Code will actually have a loop in which i am doing something , printing the 
  number in an increment order for each second.
 Then close the RDC connection(Don't turn off the remote machine. Just close 
  the RDC window)
 Wait for a min or some time and again open the RDC connection in which your VBA code is running. I should see that it should running in between close and 
open also.

```
Sub test()
    Dim V As New Visio.Application 
    V.Visible = True
        V.Documents.Add "" 
        While True
            i = i + 1
            Debug.Print i        
            V.ActiveWindow.Page.DrawRectangle 1.5, 9.25, 5.8125, 7.25    
            V.ActivePage.Shapes(1).Delete        
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))        
        Wend
     End Sub
```

But in my code when i close the RDC connection and reopen it again, I see the same value as i saw at the time of Close. It seems that it didn't run when i close the RDC connection.
No Error. Just the application stops running once we close the RDC connection.

Comment: RDC = Remote Desktop Connection ???

Comment: Did  your code have `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` anywhere? if yes then you may just think it is doing nothing because the processing power is not wasted on refreshing the visuals, but it actually doing it in the background.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Could you please elaborate this. Because i am not setting any parameter here for screen updating.